# c++ return type has pointer with type of current class

Tags: c++, class, struct, types, definition

Sorry for the bad question formulation, could not find a better way to shortly describe my problem:

I have a class A with a pure virtual method that returns an object of type B.
Class B has a member variable wich is a pointer to an object of class A.
Is there a way to achieve this?

Example:

```
class A {
public:
  B mymethod() const = 0;
}

struct B {
  std::shared_ptr<A> mypointer;
}
```

If I include the files in each other the compiler tells me that one is not declared in this scope. How can I avoid this?

Comment: Lots of circular dependency questions on SO

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::shared_ptr` was designed to replace raw pointers - so in order to provide compatible semantics, it also can be used without a full type definition.

> **Implementation notes**
>
> In a typical implementation, `std::shared_ptr` holds only two pointers:
>
> - the stored pointer (one returned by `get()`)
> - a pointer to control block

So, forward declaration is enough:

**A.h**:

```
#include "B.h"

class A
{
public:
  B mymethod() const = 0; //returns by value, so full definition of B is required (*)
};
```

**B.h**:

```
class A; //Forward declare A

struct B
{
  std::shared_ptr<A> mypointer;
};
```

---

**(*)** In fact, in your case such include may not be required, since it's only a **declaration** of function returning `B`. As long as you separate declarations (`.h`) and actual body (`.cpp`) or simply *forward-declare* functions prototypes, headers for particular types should be only included by source files, that use them.

Comment: A shouldn't need the full definition of B to simply *declare* a function that returns it. A simple declaration should be enough.

Comment: As long as it's separated from actual body - yes. I made an update, thanks for noting.